# jquery 1.9.1 on event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

With Jquery v1.5.2 following function works, I have upgraded jquery to 1.9.1 live has been replaced to **on** function. if I change live to on. its not working.

I changed on to live and included the migration plugin its working. how can I use this with **on** function

```
$( ".pop-up" ).live(
                        "click",
                            function( event ){
                                // get the id of the item clicked on
                                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                                 alert(id)
                            // block the href actually working
                            return( false );

                            });
```

Comment: is this in a dom ready state?

Comment: show your code which is not working? meanwhile on is working here http://jsfiddle.net/fWx8z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Instead of document you could use the selector that already exists in DOM, If this element is added dynamically to the DOM at a later time.

```
$(function(){
      $(document).on("click", ".pop-up",
        function( event ){
                            // get the id of the item clicked on
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                             alert(id)
                        // block the href actually working
                        return( false );
       });

});
```